# Can cordova app invoke android specific actions

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I know that you can open system apps, such as the browser, or share dialog, through cordova applications, but I was wondering if it is possible to interact with android actions, such as answering phone call, etc, through a cordova/phonegap app.

EDIT:
So, there wasn't any plugin that can do exactly what I wanted. But I wrote a small plugin https://github.com/KIvanow/installedApps which, in combination with http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.launcher can actually list and start every app on the device.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Córdova is limited for whats on the API + plugins developed by users, if you can't find a plugin for the behavior you'r looking, you need to develop your own Córdova plugin on the respective native languages.